# How can we change this date string 13MAY2022 into datetime format in python/

Tags: python, datetime, time

This is my date string `myString = "13MAY2022"`

Can anyone tell me please how can we change this **myString** into datetime format in python?

Comment: You can visit to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: Dates are binary values, not strings, and have no format. You're asking how to *parse* a string into a date. That's the job of [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> myString = "13MAY2022"
>>> dateformat = datetime.datetime.strptime(myString, "%d%b%Y")
>>> dateformat
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 13, 0, 0)
```

strptime is a method to convert date strings into date format. It's first argument is our string and the second argument is locale references in the same order and patter our string has.

For example your string has no spaces in between and is in DateMonthYear order.
Suppose you string looks like : *13-May-2022*, then the second argument would look like: **"%d-%b-%Y"**

Comment: it throw error     File "<ipython-input-5-30c4419f731b>", line 3
    dateformat = datetime.datetime.strptime(myString, "%d%b%Y')
                                                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: Your use of quotation marks is not consistent. You have written: "%d%b%Y' 
It starts with double quotes but ends with single quote.